# What's the best way to build a user to user messaging feature in codeigniter?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

e.g. like emailing but in a website..

I've googled and can't seem to find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a basic level, and sticking to the email analogy, you could store messages in a database.  An example schema would include

`message_id, sender_id, recipient_idS, subject, body, date_sent, read_status`

You would have a user table, which is where the sender and recipient id's come from.

I've googled too, and found this to send your way:
http://www.pixel2life.com/publish/tutorials/608/simple_private_messaging_system/

What kind of website are you building?  What purpose does user messaging serve there?  These pieces of information may affect how people answer.

Comment: Thanks I will check this out. The site I'm building is like a community website/social network. Users have profiles, can add friends search for friends etc.

Comment: The user messaging makes it possible for users to interact with one another. Infact it's the best best resource on the website they will have available to interact with each other other privately